# How to optimize a triple nested for loop over 3 separate arrays (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, loops, optimization, netcdf4

I have this triple nested for loop, looping over 3 separate netcdf4 arrays (for all intents and purposes, numpy arrays). Each array is a different length. The goal is to build a dictionary variable (named json) which contains time_count as the outer-most key with another dictionary as the value. Inside that dictionary, the keys are lat-lon pairs (strings) with variables as values (in this case temperature).

The code works as intended but is very slow. I'm wondering if there is a way to optimize nested loops like this, or perhaps a more efficient approach to the problem in general?

```
def create_json_dataset(netcdf_data):
    json = {}
    for time_count, temp_array in enumerate(dataset.variables['t'][:]):
        json[time_count] = {}
        for lat_count, lat in enumerate(dataset.variables['latitude'][:]):
            for lon_count, lon in enumerate(dataset.variables['longitude'][:]):
                lat_lon = str(lat) + ',' + str(lon)
                json[time_count][lat_lon] = {'temperature': dataset.variables['t'][time_count, lat_count, lon_count]}

    return json
```

Comment: It would be better to provide some input and output data for others to better understand the logic of the code.

Comment: The first thing I would do is try not making the copies with `[:]` - it's totally unnecessary, since you aren't trying to modify any of that data, but create totally new data instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following to optimize your code:

1. Assign values of dataset.variables[*some key*] outside the `for` loop so it doesn't have to get it every time.
2. Use `join` to create `lat_lon`
3. `temp_array` is unused so you can remove that

So your code could look like this:

````
var_t = dataset.variables[’t’]
var_latitute = dataset.variables[‘latitude’]
var_longitude = dataset.variables[‘longitude’]
output_json = {}

for t_index in range(len(var_t)):
    output_json[t_index] = {}
    for lat_index, lat in enumerate(var_latitude):
        for lon_index, lon in enumerate(var_longitude):
            lat_lon = “,”.join([str(lat), str(lon)])
            output_json[t_index][lat_lon] = {'temperature': var_t[t_index, lat_index, lon_index]}```
````